# Providing Estimates on Large/Complex Projects

Tags: agile, estimation

Are there any standards/guidelines which outline techniques for estimating large scale projects?

*Looking for responses that specifically address large scale projects. Large company experiences would be best.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Giving estimates for large scale projects in an Agile Environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414346/giving-estimates-for-large-scale-projects-in-an-agile-environment)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming

Answer (score 1):

The book "Software Estimation: Demystifying the Black Art" by Steve McConnel covers this question and gives references to many big companies and their publications related to their experiences and approaches in this area.